# Google Analytics - Event tracking with content grouping

Tags: events, google-analytics, analytics

I have a problem with events and content grouping in Google Analytics.

I successfully managed to get my website pages in different groups based on page typology. (ex. 'Home', 'Listing', 'Product' ...)

Unfortunately I cannot see events grouped by page typology. If I choose "Page typology (Content group)" as secondary dimension I get "not set" for all my events.

```
event 1 || (not set) || 40
event 2 || (not set) || 25
```

If I choose Page typology (Landing page content group)" it works, but I get the groups based on the first page a user visit in my website and not based on the page which fire the event.

```
event 1 || 'Home'     || 30  // home group as landing page
event 1 || 'Listing'  || 10
event 2 || 'Home'     || 15
event 2 || 'Listing'  || 10
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Events > Pages reports to see if a particular page is associated to an event. You can then use content grouping for that page.

Comment: It still gives me (not set).. I don't know why.. If I go to Website Content -> All pages and I set the grouping rule it works..